Gnome freezes while opening if WiFi is not connected
When I start up the computer, I type my password in GDM3 and I access my Gnome desktop environment. The process is easy and fast.
For the past few days I noticed that if the Wifi is not connected at the time of the connection (when I press Enter after typing my password), then desktop freezes almost instantly, even before it finished loading the screen. The cursor is still movable with the touchpad but nothing else is working.
I'm forced to hard-reboot the computer with the power button and I have to wait for the network connection while in GDM3 if I want to finally reach my desktop.
Sometimes I have to use my laptop with no connection at all so this bug is quite annoying!
I must add that this weird bug is appearing at the same time as another one, a trouble with the keyboard when starting (fixed thanks to arguments added to GRUB, about the i8042 kernel module). Seems like the recent 24.04.1 security update broke some things?
System info according to inxi:

Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ZenBook
UX325EA_UX325EA v: 1.0


Seems to be related to my Gnome extensions because if I disable all my extensions, I can access my Gnome Desktop.
I just got rid of the 2 extensions related to the web (WikiArt Wallpaper and Ollama Tray) but it kept freezing at start up. I guess that the issue is related to something that tries to connect and freezes everything when it can't connect?
